# Compiling OpenGL SOIL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, soil

How do I link SOIL for a OpenGL in Ubuntu?

EDIT:

I figured out the issue, my professor showed the locate cmd in the terminal
and I was able to find where I had to get the .h from.

If anyone else has this issue for me it was,

```
#include "SOIL/SOIL.h"
```

and to link -lSOIL when compiling

Answer (score 2):

First download the SOIL.h header file from its website

http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html

Place the header file in your project directory and put the line

```
#include "SOIL.h"
```

in your project file.
After that you have to install the soil library to use -lSOIL. To install the library use the command

```
 sudo apt-get install libsoil-dev
```

Now compile the project using gcc along with -lSOIL