# How do I install SOIL (Simple OpenGL Image Loader)?

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu

The [SOIL website](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) doesn't have any installation instructions. The file I downloaded has no readme. I failed to find anything with Google.

I doubt g++ is going to check every directory on my computer to see if it can find it. Is there a specific folder I'm supposed to put it in? Is there a script I'm supposed to run?

I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: downloading the zip file, and doing `make` from `projects/makefile` folder is the way, but I got an error - `can't create obj/image_helper.o: No such file or directory`. I had to create obj directory in `projects/makefile` (mkdir obj), and then make proceeded fine. You will find the built file at `Simple OpenGL Image Library/lib/libSOIL.a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the projects/makefile folder and type:

```
$make
$make install
```

Then you can use this library simply including SOIL.h in your C++ file.

Answer (score 9):

As suggested on [Compiling OpenGL SOIL on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739527/compiling-opengl-soil-on-ubuntu),

First download the SOIL.h header file from its website
http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html

Place the header file in your project directory and include it in your project file.

```
#include "SOIL.h"
```

After that you have to install the soil library to use -lSOIL. To install the library use the command

```
sudo apt-get install libsoil-dev
```

Now compile the project using gcc along with -lSOIL

And in case you face the error:

> undefined reference to 'SOIL_load_OGL_texture'

then link libSOIL before linking libopengl32 while compilation,for example:

```
g++ -g source.cpp -lglu32 -lSOIL -lopengl32 -lfreeglut
```

(source: [undefined reference to `SOIL_load_OGL_texture'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497497/undefined-reference-to-soil-load-ogl-texture) )

Comment: Installing SOIL by "sudo apt-get install libsoil-dev" and then referring to the header file located in the usr/include folder (#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>) is better solution in my opinion. Unfortunately, the link http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html became inactive.

Answer (score 4):

Question is about Ubuntu. However I was looking for how to get it working in Windows. But in the end is was not so complicated.

Download the [soil.zip](http://www.lonesock.net/files/soil.zip).

Browse to "Simple OpenGL Image Library\projects\VC9".

Open the SOIL.sln. I have VS15 so I had to upgrade the solution for it. It was automatic without any issues.

Then I build the solution and SOIL.lib was created.

I took this .lib file and put it in my project folder.

Added dependency in my Project - Properties/Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies

Took SOIL.h from "Simple OpenGL Image Library\src and put it in my project folder.

Then I had to include the header file

```
#include "SOIL.h"
```

and I can use it for loading image like this:

```
GLuint tex_2d = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
    (
        "pic.png",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
        );

if (0 == tex_2d)
{
    printf("SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was easy. I spent longer searching for binaries than it took to actually just build it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I found this repository [SOIL](https://github.com/kbranigan/Simple-OpenGL-Image-Library) on GitHub. Clone the repository to your machine and then perform the following operations on the command line on Linux systems: 

`make 
make install`

Then you are done!